# Aligning row with tikz picture

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, pgfplots

[image: This is my Table]

I wanted to create a table in which rows are tree  and columns are dataset, where each dataset have a boxplot in a table corresponding to each tree, but I am unable to do it correctly , the boxplot image is not starting from the top so it is not aligning to the each tree,I am unable to find a method to move it up a little bit

Here are the codes

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\listfiles
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\pgfplotsset{width = 4cm ,compat=1.8}

\begin{document}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.statistics}


\newcommand{\Abox}{ 



\begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep = 0pt ,outer sep = 0pt,trim axis left,trim axis right,baseline ]
  \begin{axis} [y=2*\baselineskip,
  ymax = 15,
  ymin = 0,
  ytick=\empty,
  %axis line style={draw=none},
  tick style={draw=none}
    ]
    \addplot+ [ 
    boxplot prepared={
      upper quartile=0.6,
      lower quartile=0.5,
      upper whisker=0.8,
      lower whisker=0.4,
      draw position=1
    },
    ] coordinates {};

        \addplot+ [ 
    boxplot prepared={
      upper quartile=0.6,
      lower quartile=0.5,
      upper whisker=0.8,
      lower whisker=0.4,
      draw position=2
    },
    ] coordinates {};
        \addplot+ [ 
    boxplot prepared={
      upper quartile=0.6,
      lower quartile=0.5,
      upper whisker=0.8,
      lower whisker=0.4,
      draw position=3
    },
    ] coordinates {};
    \addplot+ [ 
    boxplot prepared={
      upper quartile=0.6,
      lower quartile=0.5,
      upper whisker=0.8,
      lower whisker=0.4,
      draw position=4
    },
    ] coordinates {};
        \addplot+ [ 
    boxplot prepared={
      upper quartile=0.6,
      lower quartile=0.5,
      upper whisker=0.8,
      lower whisker=0.4,
      draw position=5
    },
    ] coordinates {};
        \addplot+ [ 
    boxplot prepared={
      upper quartile=0.6,
      lower quartile=0.5,
      upper whisker=0.8,
      lower whisker=0.4,
      draw position=6
    },
    ] coordinates {};
    \addplot+ [ 
    boxplot prepared={
      upper quartile=0.6,
      lower quartile=0.5,
      upper whisker=0.8,
      lower whisker=0.4,
      draw position=7
    },
    ] coordinates {};
        \addplot+ [ 
    boxplot prepared={
      upper quartile=0.6,
      lower quartile=0.5,
      upper whisker=0.8,
      lower whisker=0.4,
      draw position=8
    },
    ] coordinates {};
        \addplot+ [ 
    boxplot prepared={
      upper quartile=0.6,
      lower quartile=0.5,
      upper whisker=0.8,
      lower whisker=0.4,
      draw position=9
    },
    ] coordinates {};
    \addplot+ [ 
    boxplot prepared={
      upper quartile=0.6,
      lower quartile=0.5,
      upper whisker=0.8,
      lower whisker=0.4,
      draw position=10
    },
    ] coordinates {};
        \addplot+ [ 
    boxplot prepared={
      upper quartile=0.6,
      lower quartile=0.5,
      upper whisker=0.8,
      lower whisker=0.4,
      draw position=11
    },
    ] coordinates {};
        \addplot+ [ 
    boxplot prepared={
      upper quartile=0.6,
      lower quartile=0.5,
      upper whisker=0.8,
      lower whisker=0.4,
      draw position=12
    },
    ] coordinates {};\addplot+ [ 
    boxplot prepared={
      upper quartile=0.6,
      lower quartile=0.5,
      upper whisker=0.8,
      lower whisker=0.4,
      draw position=13
    },
    ] coordinates {};
        \addplot+ [ 
    boxplot prepared={
      upper quartile=0.6,
      lower quartile=0.5,
      upper whisker=0.8,
      lower whisker=0.4,
      draw position=14
    },
    ] coordinates {};

    
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
}



\begin{table}[h!]
\centering                          
\begin{tabular}{l l c l c l c}           
\toprule
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{ DATASET I} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{ DATASET II} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{ DATASET III} 
 \\\cmidrule(r){2-3}\cmidrule(lr){4-5}\cmidrule(l){6-7}
 &  mean & \multirow{2}{*}{boxplot} & mean & \multirow{2}{*}{boxplot} & mean & \multirow{2}{*}{boxplot} \\
 & sd.  &       & sd.   &   & sd &  \\

\midrule
\multirow{2}{*}{Tree 1} &  -0.96 & \multirow{28}{2.6cm}{\Abox}  & -0.42 &\multirow{28}{2.6cm}{\Abox} & 2.5&\multirow{28}{2.6cm}{\Abox} \\
&2.6 & &&&& \\
\multirow{2}{*}{Tree 2} &  0.09 &  & 0.04 &&& \\
&&&&&& \\
\multirow{2}{*}{Tree 3} &  0.29 &  & 0.10  &&&  \\
&&&&&& \\
\multirow{2}{*}{Tree 4} &  0.84 &  & 0.30  &&&  \\
&&&&&& \\
\multirow{2}{*}{Tree 5} &  2.19 &  & 0.80  &&&  \\
&&&&&& \\
\multirow{2}{*}{Tree 6} &  1.02 &  & 0.37  &&&  \\
&&&&&& \\
\multirow{2}{*}{Tree 7} &  -0.10 &  & -0.03  &&&  \\
&&&&&& \\
\multirow{2}{*}{Tree 8} &  -1.11 &  & -0.30  &&&  \\
&&&&&& \\
\multirow{2}{*}{Tree 9} &  1.15 &   & 0.32  &&&  \\
&&&&&& \\
\multirow{2}{*}{Tree 10} &  -1.34 &  & -0.38  &&&  \\
&&&&&& \\
\multirow{2}{*}{Tree 11} &  0.43 &  & 0.12  &&&  \\
&&&&&& \\
\multirow{2}{*}{Tree 12} &  -0.37 &  & -0.10  &&&  \\
&&&&&& \\
\multirow{2}{*}{Tree 13} &  0.41 &  & 0.12  &&&  \\
&&&&&& \\
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{TOBA } &  -0.69 &  & -0.20  &&&  \\ 
&&&&&& \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please make your code snippet be compilable? Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: As I understand your question, to me seems to be easiest to draw your table as `pgfplots` image

Comment: @Mensch , I have updated the code so it can be runned

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would probably rather create a macro that generates a single box plot for you and place this inside the table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width = 4cm, compat=1.8}

\begin{document}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.statistics}

\newcommand{\bplot}[5][blue]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
  \begin{axis}[
    xmin=0,
    xmax=1,
    y=1.5*\baselineskip,
    axis line style={draw=none},
    tick style={draw=none},
    ticks=none,
    yticklabels=\empty.
  ]
    \addplot+ [ 
    draw=#1,
    boxplot prepared={
      upper quartile=#2,
      lower quartile=#3,
      upper whisker=#4,
      lower whisker=#5,
    },
    ] coordinates {};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{table}[h!]
\centering                          
\begin{tabular}{l l c l c l c}           
\toprule
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{ DATASET I} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{ DATASET II} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{ DATASET III}  \\\cmidrule(r){2-3}\cmidrule(lr){4-5}\cmidrule(l){6-7}
 &  mean & \multirow{2}{*}{boxplot} & mean & \multirow{2}{*}{boxplot} & mean & \multirow{2}{*}{boxplot} \\
 & sd.  &       & sd.   &   & sd &  \\
\midrule
\multirow{2}{*}{Tree 1} &  -0.96 & \multirow{2}{2.6cm}{\bplot{0.6}{0.5}{0.8}{0.4}} & -0.42 & \multirow{2}{2.6cm}{\bplot{0.6}{0.5}{0.8}{0.4}} & 2.5 & \multirow{2}{2.6cm}{\bplot{0.6}{0.5}{0.8}{0.4}} \\
&2.6 & &&&& \\
\multirow{2}{*}{Tree 2} &  0.09 & \multirow{2}{2.6cm}{\bplot[red]{0.7}{0.3}{0.9}{0.2}} & 0.04 &&& \\
&&&&&& \\
\multirow{2}{*}{Tree 3} &  0.29 & \multirow{2}{2.6cm}{\bplot[brown, densely dashed]{0.5}{0.2}{0.6}{0.1}} & 0.10  &&&  \\
&&&&&& \\
\multirow{2}{*}{Tree 4} &  0.84 &  & 0.30  &&&  \\
&&&&&& \\
\multirow{2}{*}{Tree 5} &  2.19 &  & 0.80  &&&  \\
&&&&&& \\
\multicolumn{7}{c}{\centering --------- et cetera ---------} \\
\midrule
\multirow{2}{*}{TOBA } &  -0.69 &  & -0.20  &&&  \\ 
&&&&&& \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
 
\end{document}
```

[image]